# get and set the value of controls inside a panel which is itself inside a tableLayout Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, dynamically-generated

I have a tableLayoutPanel inside which i have added Panels dynamically--- the name of Panels are  :

**Panel1 ,
Panel2
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Panel10**

Now , in these dynamically added Panels , am adding some more controls dynamically such as :

**In Panel1 :** LabelDate1, LabelTime1, LabelPicAdder1,  LinkLabel1

**In Panel2 :** LabelDate2, LabelTime2, LabelPicAdder2, LinkLabel2......

Now , on a button click, i want to change the values of the controls inside the Panel1, Panel2, 
 but if i do this :

`foreach ( Control ctrl in this.tableLayoutPanel )`

, i am **ONLY** able to get the Panels into ctrl variable,

but how to get the controls inside these Panels into some variable and change the TEXT property of those controls.....

I mean, how do i get the controls which are inside the Panels, which are themselves inside the  tableLayoutPanel

TableLayoutPanel---->Dynamic Panels----------->**Dynamic Controls**  --how to change the text property of this last object in the hierarchy

Comment: iterate recursively till you get where you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the control to the panels.  So you have to iterate each panel:

```
foreach ( Control panel in this.tableLayoutPanel ) {
    foreach ( Control ctrl in panel) {
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Odds are good that you can simplify your code by storing the control references when you create them instead of trying to find them back later.

Comment: sir, do i need to add ".Controls" at the end of ---- Control panel in this.tableLayoutPanel

Comment: sir, how do i store the control references while adding them dynamically on runtime? please help

Comment: Store them in a List<> or a Dictionary<>, anything that suits you.  Start a new question if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

create a Recursive function like this to read all control in a parent and child control

```
 public void GetAllControl(Control parent)
        {
            //Dosomething with parent like setting text or blah blah blah

            foreach (Control item in parent.Controls)
            {
                GetAllControl(parent);
            }
        }
```

and call this loop every where you want

```
foreach ( Control ctrl in this.tableLayoutPanel )
{
GetAllControl(ctrl );
}
```